# How to embed my fonts in blogger?

Tags: for-loop, fonts, embed, blogger

I tried to embed fonts in my blogger website, but it didn't work when I tested it on another PC without the font installed on that PC.

This is my blog Address: ann24h.com

My font is locate in another hosting: http://kesor168.com/sub/font/

```
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: Khmer OS Dangrek;
src: url(http://kesor168.com/sub/font/Khmer_OS_Dangrek.eot);
src: url(http://kesor168.com/sub/font/Khmer_OS_Dangrek.ttf);
}
@font-face {
font-family: Khmer OS Battambang;
src: url(http://kesor168.com/sub/font/Khmer_OS_Battambang.eot);
src: url(http://kesor168.com/sub/font/Khmer_OS_Battambang.ttf);

}
</style>
```

Any idea how to fix my CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You need your name value pairs to have proper syntax. The font-family property needs `"Example Font Name"` (*single or double quotes are fine*) not `Example Font Name`

You currently only have an `.eot` and `.ttf` font files. Which only support IE9 and Safari on Android or iOS. If you have an IE fix for your `.eot` file then perhaps you'll gain support for IE6 - IE8.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Khmer OS Battambang';
  src: url('http://kesor168.com/sub/font/Khmer_OS_Battambang.eot');
  src: url('http://kesor168.com/sub/font/Khmer_OS_Battambang.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('http://kesor168.com/sub/font/Khmer_OS_Battambang.ttf')  format('truetype')
}
```

To apply it to your entire page:

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Khmer OS Battambang', sans-serif;
}
```

I have one example above, you can easily make your other font-face by using the example.

---

Edit: You asked what line would you add so it would work on Google Chrome
Answer: Add the two lines below

```
url('Khmer_OS_Battambang.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('Khmer_OS_Battambang.woff') format('woff'),
```

The 'woff2' applies to really new modern browsers.
The 'woff' applies generally to modern browsers.

Of course you'll need the `.woff` and `.woff2` files in the same directory as your other fonts. Also in the example I provided I only specified the file, you'll need to specify the directory.

Comment: if i need support Google Chrome , What's line should i add ?

Comment: I edited my answer so you can add support for Google Chrome, which is classified as a modern browser.